# Getting Internal Server Error while inserting document in the mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, gunicorn

**Issue:**
Hi, I am getting an internal server error while inserting a document into MongoDB. Document insertion is sometimes successful and sometimes not.
MongoDB connection is working successfully

**Versions:**

- Python 3.7
- PyMongo 3.12.1

**Error Logs:**

```py
Internal Server Error: route
Traceback (most recent call last):
collection.insert_one(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 708, in insert_one
    session=session),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 622, in _insert
    bypass_doc_val, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 610, in _insert_one
    acknowledged, _insert_command, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1552, in _retryable_write
    return self._retry_with_session(retryable, func, s, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1438, in _retry_with_session
    return self._retry_internal(retryable, func, session, bulk)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1470, in _retry_internal
    return func(session, sock_info, retryable)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 605, in _insert_command
    retryable_write=retryable_write)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 726, in command
    self._raise_connection_failure(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 721, in command
    exhaust_allowed=exhaust_allowed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 152, in command
    reply = receive_message(sock_info, request_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 200, in receive_message
    _receive_data_on_socket(sock_info, 16, deadline))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 291, in _receive_data_on_socket
    chunk_length = sock_info.sock.recv_into(mv[bytes_read:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 203, in handle_abort
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: Is `gunicorn` initiating an _abort_?